# Scalability issues in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm facing scalability issues in Android WebView. My code is correct and I'm even getting the proper output. Problem is that the output isn't fitting the device/emulator window. It is zoomed-in.

Following is my code:

```
        public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
        WebView wb;
        private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
      }
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.worlditlab.com");
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Following is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried all combinations of fill_parent and wrap_content hoping something will happen, but I get the same output every time. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add wb.getSettings()setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
- set all your android:layout_xx to fill_parent
- I would set the WebViewClient before the loadUrl() call
- Unless your app must do something on the url, you don't need to call view.loadUrl(url) yourself in shouldOverrideUrlLoading(). Simply return false.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I tried everything you asked me to. Is there something that I could be missing?

Comment: Try adding wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true), along with the others things above (sorry, i forgot this one).